# iPad book framework/platform/pattern available?

Tags: ipad, frameworks, sdk, ios

I have just started with iOS development (getting close to finishing my first app).  For my next app I want to convert a children's book that my wife wrote and illustrated into a free iPad book.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a framework that would provide me a lot of the basics for handling page turns, basic audio, maybe a table of contents, gesture recognition, etc.

Thanks in advance!
Jason

Answer (score 3):

Try the Baker Ebook Framework http://bakerframework.com/

Comment: Is it possible to do a full text search using this framework? If not how do i get to it if this functionality is needed in my app?

Answer (score 1):

1. free HTML5 ebook framework http://bakerframework.com/
2. laker http://www.lakercompendium.com/
3. pug pig  http://pugpig.com/
4. bakershelf https://github.com/nin9creative/baker